# Value error array with 0 features in linear regression scikit

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

My input and output data are written in an 6xn row-column excel file,thatI read them using pandas

using this code :

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl as pyx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = r"E:\"
os.chdir( path )

data1 = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx", header=None,index=False)
data2 = pd.read_excel("target.xlsx", header=None,index=False)

# print df.head()

le= 20;lg=len(data1)
x_train=[];x_t=[];y_train=[];y_t=[];x_test=[];x_ts=[];y_test=[];y_ts=[];
for i in range(le):    
    x_t = data1.iloc[i,:]
    x_train.append(x_t)
    y_t = data2.iloc[i,:]
    y_train.append(y_t)
    if i > le :
        x_ts = data1.iloc[lg-i,:]
        x_test.append(x_ts)
        y_ts = data2.iloc[lg-i,:]
        y_test.append(y_ts)



ols = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model = ols.fit(x_train, y_train)

print (model.predict(x_test)[0:5])
```

I get this error :

> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 880, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "E:/Scikit-Learn.py", line 46, in 
>       print (model.predict(x_test)[0:5])
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py",
>   line 268, in predict
>       return self._decision_function(X)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py",
>   line 251, in _decision_function
>       X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 424, in check_array
>       context))
>
> ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(1, 0)) while a
>   minimum of 1 is required.

Comment: You should spend more time reading your error messages and do some more debugging work by printing out the values of your variables for instance, because this is an error you should be able to catch by yourself.

Comment: I actually did it, that's a pity I didn't delete the question before your negative vote

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the array you feed into `predict` has `shape=(1,0)` meaning that it must be an empty iterable.

And by looking at your code, it's easy to see why. `x_test` starts of as empty, and in your code, the only way to add things to it is if `i > le`. But since your loop is defined as `for i in range(le)`, by definition `i` will never be greater than `le` since the last value of `range` is `le-1`